# Using UseEffect to Call an Endpoint

Tags: react-hooks, use-effect

I'm using the excellent work of Robin Wieruch to understand how to make a call to an API Endpoint.  Here's one of his projects: https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/react-hooks-introduction

Shown below is a modified version of his `useDataApiHook-example`.  With it I wired up two buttons, which then give me 3 ways to query an endpoint.  I've chosen to use the same endpoint in all cases but have tested it with different endpoints and it seems to work fine.

```
import React, {
  Fragment,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useReducer,
} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const dataFetchReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_INIT':
      return { ...state, isLoading: true, isError: false };
    case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    case 'FETCH_FAILURE':
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: true,
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

export const useDataApi = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
  console.log('Starting useDataApi');
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, {
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false,
    data: initialData,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      console.log('Dispatching FETCH_INIT');
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_INIT' });

      try {
        const result = await axios(url);

        if (!didCancel) {
          console.log('Dispatching FETCH_SUCCESS');
          dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: result.data });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (!didCancel) {
          console.log('Dispatching FETCH_FAILURE');
          dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_FAILURE' });
        }
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      didCancel = true;
    };
  }, [url]);

  return [state, setUrl];
};


function App() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('redux');
  const [{ data, isLoading, isError }, doFetch] = useDataApi(
    'http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux',
    { hits: [] },
  );

  const handleTestButton1Click = (event) => {
    console.log('Test Button 1 pressed');
    doFetch(
      'http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=canada',
    );
  };

  const handleTestButton2Click = (event) => {
    console.log('Test Button 2 pressed');
    doFetch(
      'http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=germany',
    );
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form
        onSubmit={event => {
          doFetch(
            `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=${query}`,
          );

          event.preventDefault();
        }}
      >
        <input
          type="text"
          value={query}
          onChange={event => setQuery(event.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => handleTestButton1Click()}>Test 1</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
        <button type="button" onClick={() => handleTestButton2Click()}>Test 2</button> 
      </div>  

      {isError && <div>Something went wrong ...</div>}

      {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading ...</div>
      ) : (
        <ul>
          {data.hits.map(item => (
            <li key={item.objectID}>
              <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have a few questions:

1. Suppose I don't want to call the query upon component load (and don't want a GET request going out upon load).  How would one do that?
2. Imagine that the events triggered by Buttons 1 & 2 were actually each calls to different API Endpoints.  For example, Button 1 could represent a call to find out if a particular username just entered already existed.  Button 2 could represent a call to find out if an e-mail address just entered already existed.  In such cases, what is the common practice to ensure that the new `data` populated by `doFetch` is used properly?

If Question 2 is not clear, let me say it another way: In all cases, the `data` object is populated by `useDataApi`.  But if the first call to `useDataApi` is intended to populate one thing, the second call is intended to populate something else, and the third call is intended to populate yet something else again, what's the best way to handle such logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Suppose I don't want to call the query upon component load (and don't want a GET request going out upon load). How would one do that?

You may pass an empty string to your hook and create a condition that fetch isn't triggered when API endpoint is empty:

```
// I've removed initialUrl
export const useDataApi = (initialData) => {
  console.log('Starting useDataApi');
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(dataFetchReducer, {
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false,
    data: initialData,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!url) {
      return;
    }

    let didCancel = false;

    ...

  }, [url]);

  return [state, setUrl];
}
```

> Imagine that the events triggered by Buttons 1 & 2 were actually each calls to different API Endpoints. For example, Button 1 could represent a call to find out if a particular username just entered already existed. Button 2 could represent a call to find out if an e-mail address just entered already existed. In such cases, what is the common practice to ensure that the new data populated by doFetch is used properly?

It's up to you. In my point of view, the advanced part to handle new data you already did: using a reducer. I'd consider populating `data` as an object in which each property is an id of each API response. I mean, if all APIs return a field `type`, I'd use it to save data this way:

```
const type = ... // get type from payload
const { data } = state;

// if you want to replace old data
data[type] = action.payload;

// if you want to append new data
data[type].push(action.payload)

return {
  ...state,
  isLoading: false,
  isError: false,
  data,
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Pedro!  Your response is very comprehensive.

Comment: I'm revisiting this question about one small but, I think, important thing.  What has been causing me confusion is this use case:
  - Make a call with `doFetch` and get back a `200` code and some data
  - Make a 2nd call with `doFetch` and get back a `404` code and ... the same data from the first call!

This clearly can't be correct so I've added `data: null` to what's modified in the `state` in the `FETCH_FAILURE` case of `dataFetchReducer`.

Now the logic in my app works properly.

Most interested in your thoughts if you disagree with this approach.